# NGINX reload CRL file from external server

Tags: nginx, openssl

I want to enable the CRL on my nginx server.
We are using a trusted CA and downloaded the first crl file.
Now the crl file is maintain by the CA and we want to fetch the file every 1 hour so that to check the status with the latest CRL file.

I have not found any way to download the CRL every hour. Can someone specify any way? My actual crl file lies at 
http://example.com/ca.crl
So want to download this file every hour and replace in nginx.

```
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  _;

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    ssl_client_certificate ca.pem;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    ssl_crl ca.crl;
    ssl_verify_depth 1;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Nginx don't have a mechanism to update the crl itself. what you can do is create a cronjob like this

```
0 * * * * wget http://example.com/ca.crl -O /path/to/ca.crl
1 * * * * /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

That will update your crl and reload the nginx configuration.

Comment: Is it really necessary to reload nginx afterwards?